# Android Camera2 synchronise image and metadata

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have a camera class using Android Camera2 API, and there are two callbacks when a frame comes in. One is the callback associated with the `surface` which receives the actual image pixel data. In this case

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnPreviewImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(final ImageReader reader) {
        Image previewImage = reader.acquireLatestImage();
        // Use previewImage
    }
};
```

This is wired in by assigning it to an `ImageReader` with `setOnImageAvailableListener`, and using that `ImageReader` when calling `createCaptureSession.`

Meanwhile, there is a second callback which receives the `CaptureResult` metadata.

```
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback previewCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
        // process(result);
    }
};
```

This is wired in by passing previewCallback to capture sessions' `setRepeatingRequest` or `capture` methods.

The question is how to coordinate the two callbacks, so as to be sure that the image and CaptureResult refer to the same capture event. This is of course necessary for any sort of advanced reprocessing, such as using images with different exposure or focus settings for bokeh or HDR creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [TotalCaptureResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult#SENSOR_TIMESTAMP) and the [Image](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image#getTimestamp()) come with a nanosecond timestamp.
They are guaranteed to have the same timestamp for the same frame.

So each time you receive one, put it in a queue or similar and once you have a pair with matching timestamps, forward the pair onward to processing.

For robustness, this requires correctly handling capture errors which can cause either the result or the image to be lost, otherwise you'll either have orphan objects in the queue that never get handled, or you'll stall your whole app waiting for an object that'll never arrive. Or both.
A simple option might be to just discard objects that are more than a second or two old.

Comment: That seems to be what I'm after. Thank you. I got myself stuck looking into SYNC_FRAME_NUMBER from the source but absent from the documentation, and somehow overlooked the time synchronisation. (And thank you particularly for the warning about robustness)

Comment: This is not correct. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977579/android-camera2-compare-image-timestamp-with-captureresult-sensor-timestamp
You cannot be sure whether the image's timestamp is always equal to the corresponding timestamp from TotalCaptureResult in case of repeating requests.

Comment: Timestamp will match perfectly but they will be of different images. TotalCaptureResult will show completely different metadata while image's metadata will be different.

Comment: Repeating requests are no different than regular captures, and you're likely seeing a device-specific bug in the case of comparing JPEG EXIF and CaptureResult metadata, unfortunately.

Comment: @EddyTalvala There is no documentation about `onCaptureCompleted` firing before `onImageAvailable` however during my tests, it happened that it was always the case. Do you know if this is guaranteed or not ?

Comment: It is not guaranteed.  Turning on more expensive outputs like face detection results may slow down onCaptureCompleted, for example,  and onImageAvailable may be faster for some formats than others (RAW_SENSOR will probably be output earlier than JPEG, for example).  So don't rely on that order.